# Scaling moves iframes apart

Tags: iframe

I got a little issue with resizing the content of iframes. there are 4 iframes on my website on a 2*2 grid.

but when i want to resize the content to fit the iframe size, the iframes get smaller and suddenly there is a big distance between the iframes.

this is the code i used to resize

.scaled-frame {

```
        zoom: 1.2;
        -moz-transform: scale(0.71);
        -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
        -o-transform: scale(0.71);
        -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.71);
        -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;

    }
```

any ideas how to solves this or what i am doing wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is how i've done it:
Use a percentage for the width. Use the corrent settings for zoom, and -moz-transform scale.

```
#frame {
    width: 47%;
    zoom: 1.00;
    -moz-transform: scale(1.00);
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

Comment: hey. thanks. that solves one issue. on the site i have two buttons to increase/decrease the size of the iframes. when i increase them they start to overlap each other and when i decrease they move apart from eachother again. any solutions to that too? thanks

Answer (score 0):

here is my code:

```
 .scaled-frame {
        width: 1024px;
        height: 768px;
        border: 0px;
    }

    .scaled-frame {

        zoom: 1.2;
        -moz-transform: scale(0.71);
        -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
        -o-transform: scale(0.71);
        -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.71);
        -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;

    }
```

and this is the zoom +/- function

```
function Inc() {
            scale = scale + 0.05;
            $("#iframes-container > iframe").each(function () {
                //$(this).width($(this).width() + $(this).width() / 100 * 10);
                //$(this).height($(this).height() + $(this).height() / 100 * 10);
                $(this).css("zoom",parseFloat($(this).css('zoom'))+0.02);
                $(this).css("-moz-transform","scale("+scale+")");
                $(this).css("-webkit-transform","scale("+scale+")");
                $(this).css("-o-transform","scale("+scale+")");
            });
        }

        function Dec() {
            scale = scale - 0.05;
            $("#iframes-container > iframe").each(function () {
                //$(this).width($(this).width() - $(this).width() / 100 * 10);
                //$(this).height($(this).height() - $(this).height() / 100 * 10);
                $(this).css("zoom",parseFloat($(this).css('zoom'))-0.02);
                $(this).css("-moz-transform","scale("+scale+")");
                $(this).css("-webkit-transform","scale("+scale+")");
                $(this).css("-o-transform","scale("+scale+")");
            });
        }
```

thanks
hivegeist